# I cannot log in to Area 51 using Stack Exchange as OpenID

Tags: bug, area-51, login, stack-exchange-openid

I cannot log in to Area 51 using Stack Exchange as OpenID. Every time I try, I get this error message.

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> The openid.return_to parameter (http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=5af0ec85-345f-455f-b871-effd3ccda425&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F8430b00c-134e-4d1f-8981-0329dfcdd85f) does not match the actual URL (https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=5af0ec85-345f-455f-b871-effd3ccda425&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F8430b00c-134e-4d1f-8981-0329dfcdd85f&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F8430b00c-134e-4d1f-8981-0329dfcdd85f&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F8430b00c-134e-4d1f-8981-0329dfcdd85f&openid.sig=9tPh9l5WNNRo2V4mkB%2BJD8myVqTg8GAEZXc9H5QTQQE%3D&openid.signed=claimed_id%2Cidentity%2Cassoc_handle%2Cop_endpoint%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cns.alias3%2Calias3.mode%2Calias3.type.alias1%2Calias3.value.alias1&openid.assoc_handle=u-RL%21IAAAAFQyDgEPAm-4t1aR-Lf-oO2u8peaE0-ikmWGBB22TTUXQQAAAAG9PB8t4vNA8DbAY5mzm4c6OyN7DbgzIwPuzsvlN-DpaqqTbnGxiSIXAlmUtipIhw_to0ZgljDFN0uSfym9ejB1&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fopenid%2Fprovider&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3D5af0ec85-345f-455f-b871-effd3ccda425%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fopenid.stackexchange.com%252Fuser%252F8430b00c-134e-4d1f-8981-0329dfcdd85f&openid.response_nonce=2017-06-20T11%3A58%3A04Z33IsxRkU&openid.mode=id_res&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.alias3=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.alias3.mode=fetch_response&openid.alias3.type.alias1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.alias3.value.alias1=kiam.la.luno.be.me%40gmail.com) the request was made with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been now fixed. I can log in with my Stack Exchange account, on Area 51, on the same way I do with other Stack Exchange sites.